# Having hash map (get by key) like in java in PHP?

Tags: php

Well I've thought of having ArrayList in PHP because it was extremely useful in PHP, and saving a lot of time.

I thought it'd be cool to have in PHP, so I did make an arrayList class in PHP:

```
Class ArrayList
{
    public $arrayList;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->arrayList = array();
    }

    public function add($element)
    {
        $this->arrayList[] = $element;
    }

    public function remove($index)
    {
        if (is_numeric($index)) {
            unset($this->arrayList[$index]);
        }
    }

    public function get($index)
    {
        return $this->arrayList[$index];
    }
}
```

Now, I noticed I need an list type more of a `hashmap`, so I can get items by keys.
Let's say I need to get mysql db name, so Ill just do `$data->hashmap->get("db_name")`.
This will return the database name value.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has built-in data types that do what you want:

- A "hashmap" is an associative array
- An "ArrayList" is simply an array

Example:

```
$my_hash_map = array('x' => 5, 'y' => 10);
$my_hash_map['x'] + $my_hash_map['y'] // => 15

$my_array_list = array();
$my_array_list[] = 5;
$my_array_list[0] // => 5
```

See [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP arrays can have string keys. Also you could use [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php).